# Error imvalid server when publishing package to NPM

Tags: npm, npm-publish

I am trying to publish some packages at NPM, and have the following
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUp8J.png):

```
timing command:publish Completed in 207ms
verbose stack Error: invalid semver:
verbose stack at patchManltest (/Users/camilacno/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/libnpmpublish/publish.js:83:7)
...
verbos node v16.13.0
verbose npm v8.1.0 
error code EBADSEMVER
error invalid semver
verbose exit 1
```

Repo: https://github.com/camilacno/2305P

Already tried several changes in my `packages.json` and nothing works.
Has anyone already had this error?

Thanks
Camila

Comment: Could you provide `package.json` from package you want to publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Npm says that something wrong with package `version` in your `package.json`. If it is not set like in your root `package.json` file you should add it and check that it is in x.x.x format e.g. `package.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Some description",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the .npmrc here is [the official NpmJS docs for the npmrc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/npmrc).
Example:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${TOKEN}
```